# httpd.conf no www redirection extra /

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I went to http://no-www.org/ and copied thier code snipped to remove www.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, what is happening is that there is an extra slash at the end of the base url.

Example:
learntodancetango.com --> learntodancetango.com
GOOD

www.learntodancetango.com --> learntodancetango.com//
WEIRD

Any advice?  Could I provide anything else to help diagnose?  If it matters, this is a Django site.

Thanks!,
David

EDIT:  Alternatively, if the httpd conf is correct, then perhaps Django is doing this for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is in the server config, there's going to be a leading slash in the URI when the rewrite rule tries to match against it. This means that the URI `/` is matched in the grouping `^(.*)$` and the resulting target is `http://learntodancetango.com/` + $1, where $1 is `/`. So 2 //'s.

You can either remove the slash at the end of your target or add a slash outside of the grouping:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you so much.  I don't know why, but 2nd method didn't work, but 1st did.  :)